# sprintf is undefined for STM32

Tags: c, stdio, micropython, usermode

I'm making a cusermod for Micropython, and I'm trying to store a number in hex format in a string. I tried using `sprintf` however, my compiler is telling me that it's undefined. I imported `stdio.h`, `string.h` as well as some other libraries required to develop cusermods for STM32 chips, yet I van't figure out why `sprintf` isn't defined??? I've only had this issue when using format specifiers...

Here's my code!

```
int chks = checksum(mns);

char checksum[10] = "*";
char temp[6]; 
sprintf(temp, "%x\r\n",chks);
strcat(checksum,temp);

char str[23] = "$";
strcat(str,mns);
strcat(str,checksum);
strcpy(mns,str);
```

I've used `printf` and it works fine even when I use format specifiers. Has anyone had a similar issue or any idea how to solve it?

Comment: What specific compiler are you using and how did you install it?  I think you should show us your full code, the command you are using to compile it, and the exact error message you are getting.  ARM toolchains usually come with a C library that provides `sprintf` in my experience.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Using GCC and GDB and installed them through MSYS2 MinGW. 

I'm building in cygdrive terminal using the latest version of micropython with the command `make BOARD=XX USER_C_MODULES=../../../modules`, [here](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/ports/stm32/Makefile) is the makefile.

And this is the error message!
```C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\arm-none-eabi-ld.exe: build-KAIROS/kairos_GPSL70/gpsL70.o: in function `gpshide_init':
gpsL70.c:(.text.gpshide_init+0x5c): undefined reference to `sprintf'
make: *** [Makefile:689: build-KAIROS/firmware.elf] Error 1```

Comment: Note: if you know s[n]printf() you don't need strcat().

Comment: @wildplasser I thought so, but snprintf is not working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **two** places, your Makefile has the `-nostdlib` flag, which tells the linker to not link in the C standard library, which provides things like `sprintf`.

In the future, you can catch problems like this yourself by preparing a [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example), including a minimal command for compiling the example.  Since the compilation command would be minimal, you would easily be able to see suspicious options like `-nostdlib` and you would try removing such options to make the example more minimal.

Comment: Hello @david! I'm having a similar issue. In the makefile, I've seen that there are two places where they have used -nostdlib. I tried removing that, but it didn't solve my problem. Could you please give us more details regarding that?
My task: I'm building a custom Micropython firmware for my ST board using the minimal sample code of Micropython.

Comment: I think you should post your own question, after carefully reading my very first comment on this question so you know what info is needed.